# Showing correct answer count in Activity before

Tags: android, count

I am currently struggling on how to send the correct answer count number to other activity and displaying it with settext. What I am trying to do is counting the correct answers in a global array `final int[] points = {0};`, but how can I show it at the activity before?

For example a user answers 1 out of 3 questions correctly. When he goes back one activity, to the menu it says. At level 1 you answered 1/3 questions correctly. How can I do that?

This is how I count the correct answers. I have two buttons in witch I count:

```
 mYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow();
                if(type.get(count[0])){
                    points[0]++;
                    ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("Teisingai!");
                } else {
                    ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("Klaida!");
                }

mNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                initiatePopupWindow();
                if(!type.get(count[0])){
                     points[0]++;
                    ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("Teisingai!");
                } else {
                        ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("Klaida!");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the simplest level you can use shared Preference for this .

Add each question number with level in shared preference or you can make different preference for different level.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("level1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

 editor.putBoolean("Q1",true); // if answered
```

And if you want to get this in another activity just do

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("level1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean result = sharedPref.getBoolean("Q1", false);
```

Comment: Im not really used to shared preferences. Do I need to use puBollean on every answered question? or just paste your code one time? Why at the line putBollean i write true but when i am trying to get it i have to write false?

Comment: Yaa you have to write putBoolean for every answer and when getting value , that false is the fallback value or default value of that key